# ggplot2: Set alpha=0 for certain points depending on fill value

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, alpha, fill

I'm currently working on a project that involves creating plots very similar to examples in Hadley's ggplot2 0.9.0 page regarding stat_density2d().

```
library(ggplot2)
dsmall <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
d <- ggplot(dsmall, aes(carat, price)) + xlim(1,3)
d + stat_density2d(geom="tile", aes(fill = ..density..), contour = FALSE)
last_plot() + scale_fill_gradient(limits=c(1e-5,8e-4))
```

[image]

Now, what I am struggling with is a way to essentially turn alpha off (alpha=0) for all tiles not in the fill-range.  So every grey tile seen in the image, the alpha should be set to 0.  This would make the image a lot nicer, especially when overlaying on top of a map for example.

If anyone has any suggestions, this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The grey area is controlled by the na.value argument to scale_fill_gradient, but even when I specify a transparent color (like na.value=rgb(1,1,1,0)) it comes out opaque, so there must be something else going on.

Comment: Alright, so perhaps if we can set the limits of a scale_alpha_continuous to be dependent on the fill value (density), then set the alpha na.value=0...

Comment: no luck so far, although setting to `gray90` makes it look *almost* OK since that's the color of the background grid ... I actually suspect this is a ggplot "issue" (buglet/wishlist?) ... possibly related to https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/475 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
d + stat_density2d(geom="tile", 
     aes(fill = ..density.., 
     alpha=cut(..density..,breaks=c(0,1e-5,Inf))), 
     contour = FALSE)+
 scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0,1),guide="none")
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome, helped me a lot. I would give it 3 upvotes if I could.

Answer (score 12):

Another possibility, just using `ifelse` instead of `cut`.

```
d + stat_density2d(geom="tile", 
    aes(fill = ..density.., alpha = ifelse(..density.. < 1e-5, 0, 1)), 
    contour = FALSE) + 
scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0, 1), guide = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: This also works great. Could you explain why it is not sufficient to set `alpha` in the `aes(..)` options only, but why transparency of the fill area can only be controlled by setting the range with `scale_alpha_continuous`? For example, I used `alpha = ifelse(..density.. < 1e-5, 0, 0.7)` and `scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0, 0.7))` to make the fill area slightly transparent.